# Is it possible to use whatsapp web in a Docker container?

Tags: java, docker, microservices

I have created a microservice infrastructure to send messages to customers via WhatsApp. A microservice is there to forward the message via REST API to a notification provider who then sends the WhatsApp. For the service to work, I need WhatsApp Web.
If she starts my microservice and wants to send a message, it works even if I am logged in via WhatsApp Web.

Now to the problem:

I packed the microservice in Docker Container so that I can start it as a web service at Azure or AWS. However, sending the WhatsApp message doesn't work because I don't have an interface in the Docker container to WhatsApp Web.
Is there a way to create the interface in the Docker container to WhatsApp Web without having to scan a QR code?

Comment: Maybe this link can help: https://github.com/pedroslopez/whatsapp-web.js/issues/1349 . And the browserless project (Docker Image distribution) https://hub.docker.com/r/browserless/chrome

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to create the interface in the Docker container to
> WhatsApp Web without having to scan a QR code?

The answer is **NO**

But you can run Chrome inside docker and use CDP to control it.
That said, you can access QRCode via VNC and scan.
Or you can create something like [venom-bot](https://orkestral.github.io/venom/pages/Getting%20Started/creating-client.html) to wrap it.

[Karate](https://github.com/intuit/karate) is a Java test Automation Tool that uses CDP to achieve this.

Look this:

- https://github.com/intuit/karate/tree/master/karate-docker/karate-chrome
- https://github.com/mandarvaze/chrome-on-docker